# Accesing camera via Javascript, taking a picture and sending it to Firebase CloudStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, server

Good morning, I´m studiyng and have this problem to solve. I have to create the logic in Javascript with nodejs, to access the device camera (this is a webApp, not Android, thats why is coded in JS), then take a picture and then send it to my backend and save it in Firebase Cloud Storage. I´m not asking for a complex code, but if u know any source, or any repository to start working will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :D

Happy coding!

Comment: You need to provide your code and explain the problems you encountered while building the solution. People can help you to fix the issues in your code not to build your assignment from scratch

Answer (score 1):

When using Node.js as part of a web application it is used for the *server-side* component of the application and doesn't have access to any cameras on devices accessing it.

You need to use client-side code to do that.

iOS and Android devices tend to make the camera available as an option when you use a regular `<input type="file">` so you can use a normal HTML form and your usual multipart-capable body parsing library (not [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) although its documentation list some options) on your server.

If you want access to a webcan cam then you'd need to look into [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/).